# D3 time scale from array index

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, graph-visualization

I am attempting to map an array index to a time range in d3.js as I do not have individual dates for the array - I just know the values are between 1900 and 2000.

```
var data = [45,678,490...]; // length 820

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]).domain([new Date(1900, 0, 0), new Date(2000, 0, 0)]);

// line function
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) { 
    // here map i to date between domain min / max    
        return x(i); 
    })
    .y(function(d) { 
        return y(d); 
    });
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this than manually calculating a date for each array value? Perhaps calculating the step and incrementing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. It looks like you have only numbers in your array, but you're not converting them to dates in your code. Maybe you want 2 scales, one that maps the numbers in your array to a date and a second one that maps that date to coordinates? Of course then you might as well have just a single scale that maps a number to a coordinate.

Comment: I am mapping the array values [45,678,490...] to the y-axis, but my problem is mapping the array index value [0,1,2,3,4...] to a date between 1900 and 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales) to map from the index value to date:

```
var arrayScale = d3.time.scale()
                    .domain([0, data.length])
                    .range([new Date(1900, 0, 0), new Date(2000, 0, 0)]);
```